# How to make my get Facebook like script loop every 3 seconds?

Tags: php

I am building a Facebook page like counter. I want to be able to get page like updates roughly every 2-3 seconds. The result will be sent to a sql database then sent to an Arduino. First of all though, I need to get the likes from the desired page. I have the PHP script below that works great but you have to load the page every time to get an updated like count.

Would you be able to use a while loop with some sort of 2-3 second delay? or what you recommend in situation? p.s I used Dan Bilzerian's FB page as an example because his likes just keep going up up up, its ridiculous.

Thanks

```html
function facebook_count($url){
 
    // Query in FQL
    $fql  = "SELECT like_count";
    $fql .= " FROM link_stat WHERE url = '$url'";
 
    $fqlURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=" . urlencode($fql);
 
    // Facebook Response is in JSON
    $response = file_get_contents($fqlURL);
    return json_decode($response);
 
}
 
 
$fb = facebook_count('https://www.facebook.com/danbilzerianofficial');
 

// facebook like count
echo $fb[0]->like_count;
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want something running on the server that gets the updated data and stores it, or do you want something running in the client browser that updates some kind of displayed view?

Comment: You need to use an ajax call to perform the operation. Php alone will only work on page reloads. You could probably direct the page to automatically reload with javascript as a workaround, but this would undoubtedly result in horrible UI.

Comment: Thanks for the point I the right direction  Mopsyd